# What is the difference between [[textureCoordinates]] and [[position]] in Metal Shading Language

Tags: swift, avfoundation, metal

I am processing videos with metal and swift. I have a vertex shader that scales the frames to aspect fit inside my view. In my fragment shader it works well if I sample with textureCoordinates like so:
`inputTexture.sample(sampler, inputFragment.textureCoordinates);`

But if I use read with position instead, it returns the unscaled frame:
`inputTexture.read(uint2(inputFragment.position.xy));`

I am assuming that this is usual behavior, I just don't know why so I was wondering if someone could explain the difference between the two. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`textureCoordinates` - **Normalized texture coordinate**.

> For 2D textures, normalized texture coordinates are values from 0.0 to
> 1.0 in both x and y directions. A value of (0.0, 0.0) specifies the texel at the first byte of the texture data (the top-left corner of
> the image). A value of (1.0, 1.0) specifies the texel at the last byte
> of the texture data (the bottom-right corner of the image).

---

`position.xy` - **The clip space position of the vertex.**

---

```
struct RasterizerData
{
    // The [[position]] attribute qualifier of this member indicates this value is
    // the clip space position of the vertex when this structure is returned from
    // the vertex shader
    float4 position [[position]];

    // Since this member does not have a special attribute qualifier, the rasterizer
    // will interpolate its value with values of other vertices making up the triangle
    // and pass that interpolated value to the fragment shader for each fragment in
    // that triangle.
    float2 textureCoordinate;

};
```

---

- [Creating and Sampling Textures](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/creating_and_sampling_textures?language=objc)
- [Metal Coordinate Systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58702023/what-is-the-coordinate-system-used-in-metal/58782808#58782808)